# Receiving NaN error and no date output

Tags: javascript

Not sure what my problem is.  I'm trying to display the date in the "Order Placed" field, and have it calculate the total into the "Total" field.  Frustrated and I could use some help.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Order Form</title>
<!-- Modified by:  -->
<!-- This web page should display the current date in the txtDate
     textbox on the form as well as calculate the order total and display
     in the txtTotal textbox on the form. -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- hide from old browsers
function enterDate() {
//reads, formats, then displays the current date in the txtDate textbox on the order form
  var myDate = new Date();
  var myMonthNum = myDate.getMonth();
  var myDay = myDate.getDay();
  var myYear = myDate.getYear();

  var monthNames = new Array()
  monthNames[0] = "Jan";
    monthNames[1] = "Feb";
    monthNames[2] = "Mar";
    monthNames[3] = "Apr";
    monthNames[4] = "May";
    monthNames[5] = "Jun";
    monthNames[6] = "Jul";
    monthNames[7] = "Aug";
    monthNames[8] = "Sep";
    monthNames[9] = "Oct";
    monthNames[10] = "Nov";
    monthNames[11] = "Dec";

  var myMonth = monthNames[myMonthNum];

  var myNiceDate = myMonth + " " + myDay + ", " + myYear;

  document.frmOrder.txtDate.value = myNiceDate;
}

function enterTotal (quantity, price) {
  //calculates the price for each item, adds to existing totals, then displays in the txtTotal textbox
  var myTotal = parseInt(window.document.frmOrder.txtTotal);
  myTotal += (quantity * price);
  window.document.frmOrder.txtTotal.value = myTotal;  
}
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="enterDate(); window.document.frmOrder.txtWidget.focus()">
<h1 align="center">Totally Useless Parts</h1>
<h2 align="center">Order Form</h2>
<hr>
<form action="mailto:email@email.com" method="post" 
      enctype="text/plain" name="frmOrder" id="frmOrder">
  <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" 
         summary="Contains the form elements for the order form">
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><div align="right"></div></td>
      <td><div align="right">Order Placed:
          <input name="txtDate" type="text" id="txtDate"/>
      </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Mail To: </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Widgets </td>
      <td><input name="txtWidget" type="text" id="txtWidget" size="4" 
                 onChange="enterTotal(document.frmOrder.txtWidget, 4.99)"/>
      (@ $4.99 each)</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td rowspan="5"><textarea name="txaAddress" cols="50" rows="6" id="txaAddress"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Gizmos</td>
      <td><input name="txtGizmo" type="text" id="txtGizmo" size="4" 
                 onChange="enterTotal(document.frmOrder.txtGizmo.value, 2.50)"/>
(@ $2.50 each) </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>Thing-a-ma-jigs</td>
      <td><input name="txtThing" type="text" id="txtThing" size="4" 
                 onChange="enterTotal(document.frmOrder.txtThing.value, 0.95)"/>
(@ $0.95 each) </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td colspan="2"><hr></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td align="right">Total:</td>
      <td>$
        <input name="txtTotal" type="text" id="txtTotal" value="0"  onChange="enterTotal()"/> 
        (US) </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces (select it an press the `{}` button in the toolbar)!

Comment: Use something like firebug to debug your code and check your variables are correct. It is really helpful when you are dealing with JavaScript

Comment: what is the date format you want

Answer (score 0):

one problem I see is mydate used to get myDay; it should be myDate (case sensitive)

there are numerous other errors. perhaps you should be using the DOM to get all values from the form each change, otherwise the application will not be robust.

As Jayantha said, use Firebug, and I recommend also Firefox's Error Console. It will help nail down Javascript errors.

Comment: Oop!  That helped!  It is displaying the date finally.. however it says the year is 111, and last I checked we didn't go back in time 1900 years.

Comment: Hmm.. also says it's the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

`getDay()` returns an integer representing the day of the week from 1 to 6.

`getYear()` returns the year minus 1900 and is deprecated. Use `getFullYear()` instead.

So, you could do something like this

```
var myDate = new Date(),

    days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday',
            'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],

    months =["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May", "Jun",
            "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],

    myNiceDate = months[myDate.getMonth()] + " " +
                 days[myDate.getDay()] + ", " + 
                 myDate.getFullYear();

console.log(myNiceDate);
```